# Find starting row number and last row number in excel based on a value using epplus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm putting a query result into excel using EPPLUS. I have a column called category and I need to insert a new row after each category to include a subtotal.

My Excel Looks like this

```
Category |  Quantity
    A    |    5
    A    |    10
    A    |    3
    B    |    2
    B    |    3
    C    |    2
```

The only thing that's always true is that we always start at A2. Category A starts at A2 and ends at A4 but assume we don't know that, how do I get the last row for A so I can insert a row after it and then for Category B and so on.

Expected results:

```
Category |  Quantity
    A    |    5
    A    |    10
    A    |    3
  Total  |    18
    B    |    2
    B    |    3
  Total  |    5
    C    |    2
  Total  |    2
```

Query for putting data as requested:

```
sqlcmd = new sqlcommand(query, con);
sqlreader = sqlcmd.executereader();
while (sqlreader.read())
{
    ws.Cells[rownum, 1].Value = sqlreader["Category"];
    ws.Cells[rownum, 2].Value = sqlreader["Quantity"];
    rownum = rownum + 1;
}
```

New code:

```
string currentcategory = "";
string newcategory = "";
while (sqlreader.read())
{
    if (currentcategory == "")
    {
       currentcategory= global_dr["category"].ToString();
       newcategory= global_dr["category"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
       newcategory= global_dr["category"].ToString();
    }

    if (newcategory == currentcategory)
    {
       ws.Cells[rownum, 1].Value = sqlreader["category"];
       ws.Cells[rownum, 2].Value = sqlreader["Quantity"];
       rownum = rownum + 1;
    }
    else
    {
       rownum = rownum + 1;
       ws.Cells[rownum, 1].Value = sqlreader["category"];
       ws.Cells[rownum, 2].Value = sqlreader["Quantity"];
       rownum = rownum + 1;
       currentcategory = "";
    }
}
```

The above code worked for adding some empty rows for the subtotal with a few errors, here's a sample output

```
Category |  Quantity
    A    |    5
    A    |    10
    A    |    3

    B    |    2
    B    |    3

    C    |    2
    D    |    1
```

expected:

```
    C    |    2

    D    |    1
```

My current code has an error if the category only has 1 row.

More edits: Solve the above problem by adding the rows after i've filled the data.

```
 int rowstart = 1;
 while (ws.Cells[rowstart, 1].Value.ToString() != "")
 {

     if (ws.Cells[rowstart, 1].Value.ToString() != ws.Cells[rowstart + 1, 1].Value.ToString())
     {
          ws.InsertRow(rowstart + 1, 1);
          rowstart = rowstart + 2;
     }
     else
     {
          rowstart = rowstart + 1;
     }
 }
```

New problem: Once I reach the end, example last row with text in it is 10, I will get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` for row 11

Comment: `I'm putting a query result into excel using EPPLUS` - care to share the code for that?

Comment: You can edit your code to track the value of `sqlreader["Category"]` while summing the values in "Quantity".  When Category changes, write out the Total row and reset the sum variable.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the tip, i've tried that but i'm currently stuck. I've edited my main post with some new code of what i've tried based on your tip. I'm also still not sure on how I can add a subtotal for the category. I was thinking I need to get the range for each category like category A is at A1 to A3, how do i get that range?

Answer (score 1):

Following is a simple example to get you going, this will help you with how to get the last row of A.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"d:\temp\EPTest.xlsx"));
            ExcelWorksheet ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            //Get all the cells with text "A" in column "A"
            var acells = from cell in ws.Cells["A:A"] where cell.Text.Equals("A") select cell;
            //To insert row after the last identified "A" increment the row number by 1
            ws.InsertRow(acells.Last().End.Row + 1,1);
            ep.Save();
        }
```

To further understand and for examples visit [epplus.codeplex.com](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LinqExample)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - you'll likely need to do a bit of debugging since I'm totally rusty on C#

```
    const long ROW_START = 2; 

    var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    var sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

    string c;
    double q;
    string curr_c = "~~~~~~~~~";
    double tot = 0;
    long r = 0;
    long rownum = ROW_START;

    while (sqlreader.Read())
    {
        q = (double)sqlreader["Quantity"];
        c = sqlreader["Category"].ToString();

        if (c != curr_c) 
        {
            if (rownum > ROW_START)
            {
                ws.Cells[rownum, 1].Value = "Total";
                ws.Cells[rownum, 2].Value = tot;
                rownum += 1;
            }
            curr_c = c;
            tot = 0;
        }

        ws.Cells[rownum, 1].Value = c;
        ws.Cells[rownum, 2].Value = q;

        tot += q;
        rownum += 1;
    }
    ws.Cells[rownum, 1].Value = "Total";
    ws.Cells[rownum, 2].Value = tot;
```